# How to get IOPS for Endurance Storage?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I tried to add mask IOPS to SoftLayer_Network_Storage service,
but I couldn't get the value. It returns null.

For the Performance storages, I'm able to get the right value with the same API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist some differences between endurance and performance storages, regarding to the endurance storages, the IOPS depends from the storage capacity, because the IOPS are ordered per GB:

I can provide a rest request that will provide the total IOPS according the storage capacity:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$storageId/getObject?objectMask=mask[properties[type]]

Method: Get
```

Replace: $user, $apiKey and $storageId with your own information

The **PROVISIONED_IOPS** property will show the **total IOPS for the storage**.
For example, you can get a result like this:

```
"createDate": "2015-09-18T10:23:26-03:00"
"modifyDate": null
"value": "5"
"volumeId": 12312345
"type": {
"description": "The iops value passed to the network storage hardware."
"keyname": "PROVISIONED_IOPS"
"name": "Provisioned iops"
}
```

The "5" value is the total IOPS for the storage, if you divide this with capacityGb (e.g: 20 GB), you will get the IOPS per Gb (That should be the IOPS that you ordered).

> IOPS/GB = PROVISIONED_IOPS / capacityGB
>
> e.g: IOPS/GB = 5 / 20 = 0.25

Anyway, if you want to get the IOPS per GB that you ordered, try the following request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$storageId/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem[orderItem[order[items]]]]

Method: Get
```

References:

- [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage)